# Split string variable Encountered Error In jMeter Beanshell

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

using this block of code I am trying to pass two variables using a delimiter  in a queue

```
String[] words = ${gotDataCloseOrder}.split("@");
String ClosedOrderAccessToken = words[1];
String CloseOrderOrderId = words[0];
log.info("ClosedOrderAccessToken",ClosedOrderAccessToken);
log.info("CloseOrderOrderId",CloseOrderOrderId);
```

gotDataCloseOrder Variable value is something like this

```
6362cb2ab4f4ed3897cfb5cc@eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJ0eXBlIjoiZ3Vlc
```

but I am getting this error

```
2022-11-02 23:25:40,434 WARN o.a.j.m.BeanShellPreProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script. 
org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval  In file: inline evaluation of: 
``String[] words = 6362cb2ab4f4ed3897cfb5cc@eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJ0eXBlIjoiZ3Vlc . . . '' 
Encountered "cb2ab4f4ed3897cfb5cc" at line 1, column 22.
```

What is the problem and what change should i make to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't inline [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) into scripts, use code-based equivalents instead.

   Change this line:

   ```
   String[] words = ${gotDataCloseOrder}.split("@");
   ```

   to this one:

   ```
   String[] words = vars.get("gotDataCloseOrder").split("@");
   ```

   where `vars` is a shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, see [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes) for more information on this and other useful [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shortcuts
2. [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider migrating.

Comment: It dose not works for queue